# End of file expected, while updating json.settings in vscode, CSS class selector not found error

Tags: html, css, json, visual-studio-code

While I try to update the `settings.json`, I got end of file expected error

[image: 1]

I was trying add additional styling files to `settings.json`, I found this error.

I tried removing the braces, didn't work.

I tried updating `json` because the new version of HTML CSS support extension in vscode is showing CSS selector not found error for all the class which are in html file and which are properly linked to CSS file (**the screen shot is shown below**).

index.html
[image: 2]

css file
[image: 3]

Can anyone help me with

1. How to resolve the CSS support error
2. End of file error.

Comment: The "end of file expected" issue is because JSON files can only have one root element. You appear to have two.

Comment: The CSS issue is further up the file. The error gives a location (`[17, 37]`) and, if you click on the error, I believe it will take you to that location.

Comment: @Ouroborus I have attached the file which is at ```([17,37])```, the above image of html file. Can you please review.

Comment: @Ouroborus The issue regarding JSON is solved, but still the css class selector not found error is showing.

Comment: Looks like VSCode is unable to figure out your stylesheet declaration (the `<link>` element) in the HTML file so it thinks you don't have any of the classes defined anywhere. Best you can do, without changing the declaration, is either ignore those warnings or disable the "HTML CSS Support" extension.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your snippet code inside of curly brackets
For example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwfSG.jpg)